# Ionic Android inappbrowser plugin - set all links in iframe to open in system browser

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

How could I set all links inside iframe to open in system web browser, instead of WebView? I'm using [inappbrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) plugin.

```
<ion-view style="" title="iframe">
<ion-content class="has-header" overflow-scroll="true" padding="true">
    <div style="" class="list card">
        <div class="item item-divider-android">iframe content</div>
        <div class="item item-body-android">
            <div style="">
                <center>
<iframe src='{{trustSrc(iframe.src)}}' frameborder="0" width="100%"    height="500" scrolling="yes"></iframe></center>
                 </div>
            </div>
       </div>
    </ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution in that [gist](https://gist.github.com/rewonc/e53ad3a9d6ca704d402e) (I didn't write it).
Basically it declares an `angular` `filter` that converts href links into `window.open` that opens the links using **inappbrowser** plugin

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);

myApp.filter('hrefToJS', function ($sce, $sanitize) {
    return function (text) {
        var regex = /href="([\S]+)"/g;
        var newString = $sanitize(text).replace(regex, "onClick=\"window.open('$1', '_blank', 'location=yes')\"");
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(newString);
    }
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.html = "This a link: <a href='https://www.google.com'>Google</a> :)";
    $scope.plaintext = "This is a link: https://www.google.com :) "
});
```

Usage in your HTML template:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
         <h1>Before</h1>
        <p ng-bind-html="html"></p>
        <p ng-bind-html="plaintext"></p>
         <h1>After</h1>
        <p ng-bind-html="html | hrefToJS"></p>
        <p ng-bind-html="plaintext | linky | hrefToJS"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can I apply this to the iframe? I can see how it works with regular links but not sure how to apply this to links inside iframe.